Google Apis Calendar V3 en C#: Query no me regresa los eventos filtrados por TimeMin y TimeMax
Estoy usando Google Apis Calendar V3 en C#. Realizo un query de lista de eventos, quiero filtrar las fechas y horas de los eventos con TimeMin y TimeMax, pero me regresa la consulta fechas anteriores, aproximadamente 9 meses atrás ¿Cuál creen que es el problema? De antemano, gracias.


Hola te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para que vayas aprendiendo como funciona el sitio, saludos.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
